# Angular 2 body-parser

Tags: angular, post, body-parser

I am trying to parse Post body in angular 2.

I have used body-parser in node express but curious how to implement body-parser in angular 2.

Situation is like this.

A third party is posting to URL path in my application with xml content in body.
let say url is like this. http://localhost:4200/login. this path will open angular 2 logincomponent {path:'login', component:LoginComponent}. What i want to do is to parse the xml in the in the body from incoming post request posted from third party to this url.

In node express its easy but I am not using express. its purely angular 2 app.

Any help, I will be thankful

Thanks

Comment: When you say a third party is posting to your url path it sounds like you are trying to use angular 2 like a server.  Angular 2 isn't a server.  What would angular 2 do with the parsed xml from the body?

Comment: I am submitting form on their server with user credentials along with My app URL. The server authenticate the user and generate  xml with user infoemation and then redirect/ post to url sent in request. One way is to have an api endpoint but if there is a way to parse the body?